# Using IList in Entityframework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have this code where all objects are created by Entity Framework 4.1:

```
public void UpdateCustomer(int CustomerID, IList<Order> CustomerOrders)
  {
     foreach (var OrderItem in CustomerOrders)
      {
        Customer.Order = OrderItem;
      }

  }
```

When I try to assign `OrderItem` to `Customer.Order`, I receive the following error:

> Error  15  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Order' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection'

What am I doing wrong here, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Sounds like the Order property is defined as a collection of orders, not a single order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign collection of orders not an order

```
foreach (var OrderItem in CustomerOrders)
    Customer.Order.Add(OrderItem);
```